# Checking whether a character in a string is a space does not work

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, insert, whitespace

I need to add two zeroes before each part with 6 numbers in a string without deleting the spaces between these parts. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string EightByte_BinaryBuffer = "010000 010100 001001 000011"; //can provide full code with reading input from user if needed

    for (int i = 0; i < EightByte_BinaryBuffer.length(); i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            EightByte_BinaryBuffer.insert(i, "00");
        }
        else if (isspace(EightByte_BinaryBuffer.at(i)) == true) //output console just stays black for minute without any changes
        {
            EightByte_BinaryBuffer.insert(i, "00");
        }
    }
    cout << EightByte_BinaryBuffer << endl;
}
```

I also tried this alternative, but it didn't work either:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string EightByte_BinaryBuffer = "010000 010100 001001 000011"; //can provide full code with reading input from user if needed

    for (int i = 0; i < EightByte_BinaryBuffer.length(); i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            EightByte_BinaryBuffer.insert(i, "00");
        }
        else if (EightByte_BinaryBuffer[i] == ' ')
        {
            EightByte_BinaryBuffer.insert(i, "00");
        }
    }
    cout << EightByte_BinaryBuffer << endl;
}
```

For context, I'm trying to replicate a base64 converter, but stuck on step 5 (converting six-bit bytes into eight-bit bytes). Here is the full algorithm: https://base64.guru/learn/base64-algorithm/encode

Comment: I don't understand, why are you inserting two binary digits each time?

Comment: You're making the string longer without adjusting `i`. Every time you encounter a space, you're inserting characters at `i`, pushing the space back into the future. You encounter the first space an infinite number of times.

Comment: What does "didn't work" look like?  You seem to be saying there's a problem with your code, but you haven't really described what that problem is

Comment: [Is this your goal?](https://godbolt.org/z/x7z3en5nW).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it's part of base64 encoding algorhytm

Comment: @DrewDormann i uploaded a video of how it looks, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSpUhuW_Bfc . Basically console just stays black until i close it

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes, this is my goal. Thanks for the solution. But honestly i'm struggling to understand how this code works, specifically why "new_buf.pop_back()" is used

Comment: @Andrew The code basically builds a new string from the old string.  The `std::istringstream` allows `operator >>` to tokenize the input using the space as a delimeter, no different than if you entered that string from the keyboard and used `cin >> text;` in a loop.  The `pop_back()` is used to eliminate the extraneous space at the end of the new string.

Comment: [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/rfcW1ceWo).  Here I inputted the string instead of starting it out as a string variable.  You see that there is no difference except that `cin` is used -- that's the magic of `std::istringstream` -- it acts just like keyboard input, with the input already set up within the `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. One more question, that "while" loop basically scans input stream until input stream is empty (facing "\n" in the end of user input), delimiting input whenever it faces with space?

Comment: The space is the delimeter for `std::cin` or for `std::istringstream`.  When there is no more input, i.e. `operator >>` detects the end of the input, then the `while` loop terminates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @brian61354270 for pointing out my mistake with "i" counter,i was able to fix it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        for (int i = 0; i < EightByte_BinaryBuffer.length(); i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                EightByte_BinaryBuffer.insert(i, "00");
                i += 2;
            }
            else if (EightByte_BinaryBuffer[i + 1] == ' ')
            {
                EightByte_BinaryBuffer.insert(i + 2, "00");
                i += 2;
            }
        }       
}
```

There's also alternative suggested by @paulmckenzie which makes use of input stream:

```
//explanation of how this code works can be found in comments under the question

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string EightByte_BinaryBuffer = "010000 010100 001001 000011"; 
    std::istringstream strm(EightByte_BinaryBuffer);
    std::string small_buf;
    std::string new_buf;
    while (strm >> small_buf)
        new_buf.append("00" + small_buf + " ");
    new_buf.pop_back();        
    std::cout << new_buf;
}
```

Thanks for help everyone.